# Why is a field conservative if its irrotational, and why is this equivalent to saying it is described by some potential function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

We were studying conservative fields today and I am a bit confused as to how the condition $ \nabla \times \vec F  = 0 $, the field is irrotational, is equivalent to saying it is described by some function $f$ such that $F=-\nabla f$. Why is this the case. I dont see why the first reason is true, and much less why they are equivalent. I also don't see why the second case isn't true for all functions? If you integrate $F$, surely you can always find it gives a function $f$?

Comment: Note that this isn't _obvious_, but rather an important theorem. Read a proof, and if there is any step there that you feel uncertain about, you can ask us to help you out. As to your last question, what do you mean "integrate" when the functions are vector fields in higher-dimensional Euclidean space? That's not a straight-forward concept.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something intuitive I was missing. 

Also I was still thinking in terms of a single variable, i.e the gravitational force is $GMm/r^2$, which you can just integrate wrt $r$ to get the potential. Not sure if you can just do a straight forward integral when it comes to a force described by more than 1 variable.

Comment: There’s an important condition that is often glossed over: the domain of $\vec F$ must be simply-connected. I’m sure that you’ll soon be shown (or given as exercises) examples of irrotational vector fields that aren’t conservative.

Comment: The usual method taught for finding the potential function involves going back and forth between integrating and differentiating w/r a single variable at a time. However, the potential function can also be computed via a line integral of $\vec F$.

Comment: On your final comment "If you integrate $\vec F$, surely you can always find it gives a function $f$"? Not in more than one dimension. In one dimension, there is only one path to get from some starting point $a$ to the point $x$, so when you integrate in one dimension, there is only one possible result. But in $2$ or more dimensions, There are infinitely many paths from $a$ to $x$, and integrating $\vec F$ along different paths need not give the same answer. It is only when $\vec F$ gives the same answer when integrated over all paths (ie, when $\vec F$ is conservative) that $f$ can be defined